# Python skimage image with one value for color definition

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, numpy, scikit-image

I just started working with `skimage` and I am using it in python.3.6 with the `skimage-version: 0.17.2`
And I started using the example form: https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/user_guide/numpy_images.html
There I found something that I did not understand. The color of this image is only defined by one singe value in the numpy-array. How can that be? Is it nit using RBG or something like this?
My code looks like this:

```
from skimage import data

camera = data.camera()
print(camera.shape)
print(camera[0,0])
```

And the output is:

```
(10, 100)
0.0
```

What is driving me crazy is the `0.0` shouldn't it be something like `[0,0,0]` for white in this example ?

When I show the image I get following result :[image: image i get]
Can anybody please help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The color is defined by a single value because it's not RGB, it's greyscale. So the image shape is `(512, 512)`, and not `(512, 512, 3)`. As a result, if you pick a single *white* point it will be `[255]` and not `[255, 255, 255]`.

If you're confused because the picture isn't black and white, it's just because the default colormap of `matplotlib` is viridis, so green and yellow. This doesn't change the pixel values, it's essentially just a "theme" or camera filter. If you changed the colormap to grays, you will get:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.imshow(255 - camera, cmap='Greys')
plt.show()
```

[image]

If you don't specify the colormap, even a random array of pixels will get the yellowish tint:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4, 4))
plt.imshow(np.random.randint(0, 256, (512, 512)))
plt.show()
```

[image]

There is one thing I don't understand, though. The pic seems inverted. I had to subtract the pixel values from 255 to get the normal camera pic.